# API calls in Python, 2 different JSON Strings

Tags: python, json, api

I'm trying to call API's from various cryptocurrency exchanges in PYTHON.

This is the API JSON-string that gets returned by the following URL (https://api.mintpal.com/v1/market/stats/uro/BTC)

```
[
    {
        "market_id": "210",
        "coin": "Uro",
        "code": "URO",
        "exchange": "BTC",
        "last_price": "0.00399700",
        "yesterday_price": "0.00353011",
        "change": "+13.23",
        "24hhigh": "0.00450000",
        "24hlow": "0.00353010",
        "24hvol": "6.561",
        "top_bid": "0.00374001",
        "top_ask": "0.00399700"
    }
]
```

I'm interested in getting the "Last Price", I print it using the following code.

```
import urllib2
import json


url = 'https://api.mintpal.com/v1/market/stats/URO/BTC'
json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url)
URO_data = json.load(json_obj)
for item in URO_data:
    URO_last_price = item['last_price']

print URO_last_price
```

So far so good. However, I'm trying to do the same thing for the Bittrex exchange using the following URL (https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummary?market=btc-uro)

The JSON String returned looks as follows:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "",
    "result": [
        {
            "MarketName": "BTC-URO",
            "High": 0.00479981,
            "Low": 0.00353505,
            "Volume": 30375.93454693,
            "Last": 0.00391656,
            "BaseVolume": 120.61056568,
            "TimeStamp": "2014-07-29T17:54:35.897",
            "Bid": 0.00393012,
            "Ask": 0.00395967,
            "OpenBuyOrders": 182,
            "OpenSellOrders": 182,
            "PrevDay": 0.00367999,
            "Created": "2014-05-15T05:46:29.917"
        }
    ]
}
```

This JSON string has a different structure then the one before, and I can't use my first code to get the value "LAST". However, I can work around it by printing 'string index', but that's not a solution.

```
url = 'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=btc-uro'
json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url)
URO_data = json.load(json_obj)

URO_String = str(URO_data)
last_price = URO_String[79:89]

URO_LastPrice = float(last_price)

print last_price
```

I want to get the value of "Last" in the second JSON string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Json is best thought of as a bunch of layers, and you need to get the information you need by going layer by layer.

The first layer you need to get is "result" with:

```
URO_data["result"]
```

REsult is an array, so you need to get the first item in the array by index

```
URO_data["result"][0]
```

From that object, you need to get the Last entry

```
URO_data["result"][0]["Last"]
```

That should work, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: I should have asked for help sooner. I've been dieing to find out for the last couple of days. Appreciate your help. It works now!

Answer (score 0):

You can access it as bellow,

```
>>>
>>> url = 'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=btc-uro'
>>> json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url)
>>> URO_data = json.load(json_obj)
>>> URO_data['result']['Last']
0.00396129
>>>
```